# SVG *pattern* stroke color change on hover with pure CSS?

Tags: html, css, svg

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <title>test</title>

 <style>
  body, html {
  height: 100%;
  background-color:#eee;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  overflow: hidden;

}

path {
  fill: #eee;
  stroke: #000;
  stroke-width:1;
  pointer-events: visible;
}


 </style>
</head>
<body>
<svg width="100%" height="100%" >
    <pattern id="pattern-hex" x="0" y="0" width="112" height="190" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" viewBox="56 -254 112 190">
      <g id="hexagon">
        <path class="bla" d="M168-127.1c0.5,0,1,0.1,1.3,0.3l53.4,30.5c0.7,0.4,1.3,1.4,1.3,2.2v61c0,0.8-0.6,1.8-1.3,2.2L169.3-0.3 c-0.7,0.4-1.9,0.4-2.6,0l-53.4-30.5c-0.7-0.4-1.3-1.4-1.3-2.2v-61c0-0.8,0.6-1.8,1.3-2.2l53.4-30.5C167-127,167.5-127.1,168-127.1 L168-127.1z"/>
        <path class="bla" d="M112-222.5c0.5,0,1,0.1,1.3,0.3l53.4,30.5c0.7,0.4,1.3,1.4,1.3,2.2v61c0,0.8-0.6,1.8-1.3,2.2l-53.4,30.5 c-0.7,0.4-1.9,0.4-2.6,0l-53.4-30.5c-0.7-0.4-1.3-1.4-1.3-2.2v-61c0-0.8,0.6-1.8,1.3-2.2l53.4-30.5 C111-222.4,111.5-222.5,112-222.5L112-222.5z"/>
        <path class="bla" d="M168-317.8c0.5,0,1,0.1,1.3,0.3l53.4,30.5c0.7,0.4,1.3,1.4,1.3,2.2v61c0,0.8-0.6,1.8-1.3,2.2L169.3-191 c-0.7,0.4-1.9,0.4-2.6,0l-53.4-30.5c-0.7-0.4-1.3-1.4-1.3-2.2v-61c0-0.8,0.6-1.8,1.3-2.2l53.4-30.5 C167-317.7,167.5-317.8,168-317.8L168-317.8z"/>
      </g>
  
  </pattern>
   
  <!-- The canvas for our pattern -->
  <rect x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%" fill="url(#pattern-hex)" />
  
</svg>
</body>
</html>
```

How would I go about changing the SVG pattern's stroke color on hover via CSS? I read elsewhere that SVG patterns might not accept pure CSS hover changes, and I'd have to rely on JS events attached to the individual paths?

Comment: technically you cannot because it's a pattern so the elements aren't independant to catch hover on each one

Comment: @TemaniAfif so would attaching JS events to each hexagon in the example fix that?

Comment: that's the issue, you don't have *each* hexagon. If you have the individual hexagons it would be easy

Comment: @TemaniAfif Understood. Any idea to make this easier? other than some convoluted document.write for every hexagon?

Comment: document.write and SVG don't go together. Just use DOM e.g. createElementNS to create hexagons from polygons.

Comment: Understood. Thank you, Temani & Robert!